# What happens when an Account Team Member is removed and they are also Case Owners of the account?

Tags: case, account, sharing, account-teams

Scenario:

Account A has Account Team Member ATM1, ATM2, ATM3. (Account Access Level (Read/Write), Case Access Level (Read/Write)).

Now ATM2 created a case on the Account A, so by default he becomes the owner of the case. Now lets say we remove ATM2 from Account A, as he is still the owner of the case, he still will have access to the account, right?

Do we have to manually take care of removing the ownership of the Case and reassign the case to someone else from the ATMs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think as ATM2 is owner of the Case and there is related parent Account of the Case so ATM2 will have the access of the Account. Now what kind of access ATM2 have will be dependent on the Case OWD settings.

*Sharing between accounts and child records
Access to a parent account—If you have access to an account’s child record, you have implicit Read Only access to that account.
Access to child records—If you have access to a parent account, you have access to the associated child records. The account owner's role determines the level of access to child records.*

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sharing_across_objects.htm&type=5